# Calculation with an action button and using in another ObserveEvent

Tags: r, shiny

Let's say I have two action buttons. When I press "Go!", I want to calculate a value and then, by the pressing the second action button, I want to use the calculated value in another calculation. This code does not work and gives an error like this:

"Warning: Error in observeEventHandler: object 'coeff' not found"

Why it does not give me an answer?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = "AB", label = "Go!"),
  actionButton(inputId = "AB1", label = "Calculate!")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$AB,{
    coeff <- sum(1:15)
  })

  observeEvent(input$AB1,{
    calculatedValue <- coeff*10
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're best to use `reactiveValues` as internally `observeEvent` doesnt know what `coeff` is, as it thinks its a local variable only, so try this code below. You can access the values with `v$coeff` and `v$calculatedValue`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = "AB", label = "Go!"),
  actionButton(inputId = "AB1", label = "Calculate!"),
  textOutput("myValue")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  v <- reactiveValues()

  observeEvent(input$AB,{
    v$coeff <- sum(1:15)
  })

  observeEvent(input$AB1,{
    v$calculatedValue <- v$coeff*10
  })
  output$myValue <- renderText( v$calculatedValue)

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: how would you display the clculated value in the ui?

Comment: if you're not familiar how to display simple things like values via `renderText`, then you should definitely do the tutorials on shiny page https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/. Note I added a simple example how to `renderText`